# What is the return value of a complex alias in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

When I execute a command that has been alias to a series of commands, what value gets returned back to the shell?  Also, assuming I have an alias defined like this:

```
alias doit 'cd ~/some/dir; ./my_app; cd -'
```

How can I make the return value that `./my_app` returns the return value of the entire aliased command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alias is almost a textual substitution. So after your alias definition, typing `doit` is equivalent to typing `cd ~/some/dir; ./my_app; cd -`. This is a syntactically correct list of commands, and its return value is the return value of the last command in the sequence, here `cd -`.

Other answers show a general way of saving the status of an intermediate command and returning it. However, in this specific case, there is a better way to express this sequence of actions: instead of changing to another directory and then changing back, execute the action that requires a different current directory inside a subshell, so that the current directory of the shell doesn't change at all.

```
doit () {
  (cd ~/some/dir && ./my_app "$@")
}
```

I've made two additional improvements:

- Use `&&` rather than `;` between the commands, so as not to try to execute `my_app` if the `cd` command failed.
- Allow arguments to be passed to `my_app`: if you run `doit foo bar`, `my_app` is invoked with the two arguments `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: Excelent answer, thanks!  One question: What is it that cause this to be run in a sub-shell?  Is it the wrapping of the commands in parenthesis or just the fact that they are being run in a shell function?

Comment: @heavyd: The parentheses are the syntax for subshells. The code in a shell function is not isolated from its context, so that you can e.g. run `cd` in a function and have it affect the caller.

Answer (score 1):

The value returned is the exit status of the last command executed.

Maybe you should use a function instead:

```
function doit
{
    cd ~/some/dir
    ./my_app
    local X=$?
    cd -
    return $X
}
```

From `man Bash`:

```
$? Expands to the status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline.
```

---

**Note:** The `local` command ensures that no global variable (with same name) is modified.

Answer (score 0):

Code blocks in the shell generally return the return value of the last command in the block. In your case, that would be `cd -`, which is unlikely to ever fail.

I think you can get what you want by turning that alias into a shell function:

```
doit () {  
    cd ~/some/dir  
    ./my_app  
    RETVAL=$?  
    cd -  
    return $RETVAL  
}
```